# Cannot get error object from window.onerror while using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
window.onerror = function(message, filename, lineno, colno, error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
};
```

Without `reactjs`, everything is fine. I can get the stack.

With `reactjs` I get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null
window.onerror                              @ index.html:9
ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback       @ ReactErrorUtils.js:71
executeDispatch                             @ EventPluginUtils.js:79
executeDispatchesInOrder                    @ EventPluginUtils.js:102
executeDispatchesAndRelease                 @ EventPluginHub.js:43
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel         @ EventPluginHub.js:54
forEachAccumulated                          @ forEachAccumulated.js:23
EventPluginHub.processEventQueue            @ EventPluginHub.js:259
runEventQueueInBatch                        @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:18
ReactEventEmitterMixin.handleTopLevel       @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:34
handleTopLevelWithoutPath                   @ ReactEventListener.js:93
handleTopLevelImpl                          @ ReactEventListener.js:73
Mixin.perform                               @ Transaction.js:136
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates                              @ ReactUpdates.js:94
ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent            @ ReactEventListener.js:204
```

In file `ReactErrorUtils.js`:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  /**
   * To help development we can get better devtools integration by simulating a
   * real browser event.
   */
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.dispatchEvent === 'function' && typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof document.createEvent === 'function') {
    var fakeNode = document.createElement('react');
    ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback = function (name, func, a, b) {
      var boundFunc = func.bind(null, a, b);
      var evtType = 'react-' + name;
      fakeNode.addEventListener(evtType, boundFunc, false);
      var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
      evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
      // Line 71
      fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
      fakeNode.removeEventListener(evtType, boundFunc, false);
    };
  }
}
```

It seems that `reactjs` hijack the events, and dispatch new event which lacks the error argument.

How can I get stack from error?

Answer (score 1):

Although this should not happen, it could be React's internally used class names conflicting with the class names of your application. I Googled the problem and found a forum where someone fixed this exact problem by changing his class names.

React has been known to give errors which are misleading or give surprisingly little detail (i.e. `Invariant Error`)

Comment: Errors should have a stack. see below: http://embed.plnkr.co/kVAO57uMS3lVuqDuo9SM/

Answer (score 1):

New updates from **React 16**.

There is a new life cycle method [componentDidCatch](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) which is triggered when there is an error inside the child components.